# Play Framework 2.1.1: bindFromRequest() returns the correct data but ignores all data pertaining to relations

Tags: playframework-2.1

I have a form that is supposed to create an entity of type Load, but for some reason, doesn't seem to be actually passing or seeing any of the data related to associations of the entity (load.user, load.client, etc). This all used to work fine but stopped working at some point during a bunch of refactoring (that didn't change any of the fields in any of the models). Now all of the forms in my website have broken the same way and I have no clue where to even look to start fixing it.

From the view, I submit the form for a new Load, printing out the data everywhere I can along the way. Printing out the data being sent to the server before it's sent shows all the data is there like it should be. Printing out `Form.form(Load.class).bindFromRequest()` in the controller shows the form's data contains everything needed, for example, the value `user.id=1` is in the data. However, there is also a validation error saying that the user is missing. How can this be?

`Form(of=class models.Load, data={ a bunch of stuff, user.id=1, a bunch more stuff}, value=None, errors={=[ValidationError(,Logged in user is missing or invalid.,[])]})`

The validation error is being generated by `public String validate()` in the Load class, which is simply checking `if(user==null)` and returning that string if it is. I should note that every form that submits multiple entities (for example, submitting a Dock and then also the Dock's Location) only saves the main entity (in this example, the Dock) and ignores all others (the Dock's Location is never saved, even though Dock cascades in the model to also save the Location). All of our form fields are labelled correctly, this code did used to work at some point before it mysteriously stopped working!

So why did all of my forms suddenly stop correctly dealing with anything but the main model for the form? It is as if they cannot even "see" the data contained in bindFromRequest(). If I print out a variable in the validation method of Load, such as this.status, it prints the correct thing. But if I try to print something like this.user.id or this.client.id I get a null pointer error. Where is the code in Play that actually interprets the data (`user.id=1`) and turns it into the User associated with the Load, and how could it be breaking?

Edit: Also, yes, I did try "play clean", it was the first thing I tried since usually it fixes weird errors like these! But this time, no dice.

Edit2: I'm including the html from the form, in case it is helpful.

`<input type="text" id="user_id" name="user.id" value="1" class="idfield">`

Edit3: The only change I made during the refactoring that might have influenced this is that I had to make some setter methods like Load.setBroker() because the ones that are supposedly generated by Play didn't work. For example, `load.broker=aBroker` would not have set the Load's Broker before, so I had to make a `public void setBroker(Broker broker)` method in Load. Does Play use the auto-generated setters to bind the data? Could overwriting them cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, I figured it out. It was the setters I had written. Some of them were set to private purely by mistake, and apparently this was preventing Play from setting the values when binding the data. Changed them all to public and the mystery error vanished.

Comment: Nice one,  I had the exact same issue, except I was trying to use public fields, even then it seems you need the setters.